# Custom PCollectionView

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

There have been a number of times when I wanted to create a custom PCollectionView. Is this possible? For now, the only workaround I have is to create a PTransform, return a PCollection, and then apply a PCollectionView.asSingleton() transform, but I've noticed (at least several months ago) that this is much slower than running a native PCollectionView transform, such as View.AsList(). And since I'll be calling this PCollectionView method millions of times, it makes a difference if it takes a few milliseconds vs say a second.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to view the contents of your `PCollection`? The answer to this question will determine how you should approach things.

Cloud Dataflow (more generally, any Apache Beam backend) has a few ways that it will materialize your `PCollection` to allow you to efficiently access it as a side input. So list, singleton, map, and multimap are each pretty efficient for their usual access patterns (iteration, key lookup, etc). The architecture of Dataflow (now Beam) is such that you *can* define custom views, but if it requires a new access pattern then it will require backend support to be efficient.

Also you might care to know that after the first access to a singleton sided input, the value will usually be cached.